# How to effectively fetch comments for posts with MongoDB/mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async.js

I have the following Post and Collection documents:

```
// posts
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56978d8cdbc511a81e7e2ea8"),
    "body" : "Post body 1",
    "created_at" : 1452772748737
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56978d3cdbc655b81e7e2e10"),
    "body" : "Post body 2",
    "created_at" : 1452772759731
}

// comments
{
    "_post" : ObjectId("56978d8cdbc511a81e7e2ea8"),
    "body" : "Comment 1"
},
{
    "_post" : ObjectId("56978d3cdbc655b81e7e2e10"),
    "body" : "Comment 2"
}
```

I need to query all posts with all comments to be the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56978d8cdbc511a81e7e2ea8"),
    "body" : "Post body 1",
    "created_at" : 1452772748737,
    "comments": [{
        "_post" : ObjectId("56978d8cdbc511a81e7e2ea8"),
        "body" : "Comment 1"
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56978d3cdbc655b81e7e2e10"),
    "body" : "Post body 2",
    "created_at" : 1452772759731,
    "comments": [{
        "_post" : ObjectId("56978d3cdbc655b81e7e2e10"),
        "body" : "Comment 2"
    }]
}
```

My schema for post and collections look the following:

```
// post 
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({

},{
    strict: "throw",
    collection: "posts"
});

PostSchema.add({
    created_at: {
        type: Number,
        'default': Date.now
    }
});

PostSchema.add({
    title: {
        type: String
    }
});

PostSchema.add({
    body: {
        type: String
    }
});

// comment
var CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({

},{
    strict: "throw",
    collection: "comments"
});

CommentSchema.add({
    _post: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }
});

CommentSchema.add({
    body: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

What is the effectively way to get the result above?

Comment: Take a look here: http://seanhess.github.io/2012/02/01/mongodb_relational.html. Why you split posts and comments into 2 collections?

Comment: can you show model defined for post and comments?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I've updated my post

Comment: @Philipp Dahse because storing embedded documents is leads to growing document in size and relocating to another disc space that leads to slow writes

Comment: Splitting posts and comments results with much slower reads. Think carefully which speed is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it through [mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) and [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). Sample codes as below.

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

Comment.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$_post', comments: {$push: '$body'}}}
    // ...
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (err)
           // error handling
        Post.populate(result, {path: "_id"}, function(err, ret) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log(ret);
        });
});
```